# Factory return returning function, not product of function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have implemented a promise inside the factory which seems to work. However I seem to be returning the function ... not the product of the function. If I console log I am seeing the full function printed out in the console instead of the data.

Have I messed up the way the data is return?

**Object {data: function}** <-- from console log

```
latestScores.factory('importIO', function($q) {

return {

    data: function(){

         var deferred = $q.defer()

         setTimeout(function() {

         var io2 = new importio("xxx", "xxx", "import.io");

         io2.connect(function(connected) {

         if (!connected) {
            console.error("Unable to connect");
            return;
         }

        var data;

        var callback = function(finished, message) {

            if (message.type == "DISCONNECT") {
                console.error("The query was cancelled as the client was disconnected");
                deferred.reject(new Error('No name specified for greeting'))
            }

            if (message.type == "MESSAGE") {
                if (message.data.hasOwnProperty("errorType")) {

                    console.error("Got an error!", message.data);
                } else {
                data = message.data.results;
                deferred.resolve(data)
                }
            }
            if (finished) {
                data = message.data.results;
                deferred.resolve(data)

            }
        };

        io2.query({
            "connectorGuids": [
                "xxx"
            ],
        }, callback);

    });

     }, delay)
    return deferred.promise

    }
}

});

latestScores.controller('ScoresController', function($scope, importIO) {

    $scope.liveScores = importIO.data; 

    console.log($scope.liveScores); /* returns a console log of function not data */

});
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) and try to promisify those `io.connect` and `io.query` functions. Then [edit] your question to show us your attempt if it didn't work out (and I'll reopen and answer the updated question).

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) on promises?

Comment: You just need to create a promise and resolve it in your callback function the same as you would with $http. Have a look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: @Sean: You don't create promises and resolve them manually using callbacks when working with `$http`?

Comment: Would I be better using a service rather than a factory and calling the service function in the promise?

Comment: @Bergi My bad, I got the success/error thing confused with promises. `$http` does use a promise internally but you're right it doesn't expose that.

Comment: @Sean: Of course `$http` does expose its promise - it does return one! Those `success`/`error` methods are only for backwards-compatibility.

Comment: @Bergi can you see if my edit has made any more sense? I was up all night trying to get it working. If not I will just close the question and start from scratch with the promises etc.Thanks for your help

Comment: @craigie2204. I'm on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the function to `$scope.liveScores` not the result.

You make use of promises like this:

```
importIO.data().then(function(result){
    $scope.liveScores = result;
    console.log($scope.liveScores);
});
```

This means you execute data function and then, after the method "data" is complete, you assign the result to `liveScores`.

Comment: Thanks for this but I am getting a delay undefined.. You have given the correct answer though its just me coding badly that is causing the problem.

I now understand better how it works

Comment: Also, you seem to be using `factories` as `services`. When using factories you create new objects from the result of a factory like: `var myThing = factory.createThing();`. I would use a service to import data not a factory. This is a problem as AngularJS documentation makes reference of factories in the Services docs page. However, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24886406/2149366

Comment: @craigie2204 Remember that promises are asynchronous, so you have to manipulate the result inside the then function, otherwise, you will be executing the rest of the code outside the `then`function before the promise has finished. That's the reason you're getting the undefined.

Comment: Thanks man yeah I thought this and checked the docs and seen what you just mentioned.. Can I ask, why do I need to put a delay at the end of my factory, is that not what the promise does?

Comment: Ah I just removed the whole timeout function, I must have copied it while playing around, still works :)

Answer (score 0):

Since importIO.data() is a function..try this:

```
latestScores.controller('ScoresController', function($scope, importIO) {

   importIO.data().then(function (result) {
        $scope.liveScores = result; 

    console.log($scope.liveScores);

});
```